# how can I render index.js.erb in js format? (ruby 1.8.7)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can I render `index.js.erb` from my controller when responding to `.js` format?

My controller's index action

```
  def index  
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @campaigns }
          format.js  ??
        end
    end
```

the JS which call the controler:

```
("#category_category").change(function(){
    param=$("#category_category").val();    
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    format: 'js',
    url: '/campaigns',
    data: {category: param}     
});
});
```

index.js.erb:

```
alert('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
```

Comment: the above JS code is  send to the controler.
in the index.js.erb I have now a simple alert.

Comment: yes.it's go to the controler,but dont as Js.
Therefore (probably) the index.js.erb dont render

Comment: try to change `$.ajax(...)` to `$.get("/campaigns",{category: param})`

Comment: I write :$.get("/campaigns",{category: param});
but it's still dont work.                                                                  
in the terminal:              
  Processing by CampaignsController#index as
 
  Parameters: {"category"=>"Celebrity"}

Comment: I wrote    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/campaigns',
    data: {category: param, format: "js"}      and it work!!
thank you very much`

Answer (score 2):

Just put format.js in your controller (like you do in your question), name your view file index.js.erb and it will be rendered out in javascript format.

Comment: thanks on your answer. I did as you write me,but it dont work. do you mean for ruby 1.8.7? In addition,I edit my quastion and add more information.

Answer (score 0):

just navigate to your controller action in the browser with .js at the end:

http://localhost/campains.js